# Cutsomise the text in ListView Android

Tags: android, listview, textview

Firstly new doing Android. Be patient. That said it's doing my head in. 6 different examples of how to customize your ListView and so far none of them work. Clearly it's me. This should be so simple I must be missing a vital step. I have watched numerous videos and read tutorials all seem to claim to get it working.

So This is what happen:

1) I have an Activity.

2) This has an StringArray of say mammals.

3) I populate the ListView with the fruit array.

4) It comes up perfectly except it has a black background, and I wanted a white background with black text.

5) Add the relevant image to the animal i.e. rabbit has a thumbnail of a rabbit (Note I didn't even get to this step)

So this is what I did after reviewing other peoples suggestions;

1) Created a custom layout called `"list_row.xml"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="50px"
            android:layout_height="50px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
            android:layout_marginRight="20px"
            android:layout_marginTop="5px"
             >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@+id/label"
            android:textSize="30px" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

2) Left my original ListView item on the visible page called `"mammals.xml"` This has the ListView in it.

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list"
          android:layout_height="300dp"
          android:layout_width="300dp"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_marginTop="114dp"
          android:divider="#b5b5b5"
          android:dividerHeight="1dp"
          android:background="#FFFFFF"/>
```

3) On the `"onCreate()"`I added the list and applied it.

```
     static final String[] MammalList = new String[] { "Rabbit", "Bear", "Deer","Kangaroo", "Emu", "Leopard" };

     private ListView m_listview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mammals);

        m_listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_row, MammalList);


        m_listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I know that in order to change HOW the row is to look you change the `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` to `R.layout.list_row`. At this point I run the application and it fails.

Can someone please point me in the right direction on how to achieve this?

Also not sure if Stack Overflow has captured all the code. I tried two different browsers both of which were having issues rendering.

ERROR BELOW

```
04-02 17:53:37.621: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30020): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:392)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:681)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `At this point I run the application and it fails.` What error do you get? Can you copy paste the error LogCat?

Comment: try changing your theme to android.holo and i guess you will get white background with black text

Comment: try changing your adapter like this...setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,MammalList));

Comment: Thanks Karan...tried it but didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell the ArrayAdapter the id of the `TextView` to use:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_row, R.id.label, MammalList);
```

In order to display more complex layouts, such as a picture, you'll have to override `getView` of `ArrayAdapter`.

I'm not sure if what you have posted for `list_row.xml` is the entire xml file, but if it is, all layouts must be enclosed in some ViewGroup (ex: `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout`, `FrameLayout`, etc). This is as simple as doing:

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent">

      .... // existing list_row.xml code here
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah something weird is happening with the rendering of my code. But what you suggested about the LinearLayout with the list_row.xml contents is what I have. I added in the R.id.label which I did not have before but still get the same error. I'll keep reviewing everyones suggestions.

Comment: Okay got it...Tushar you were correct except the R.id.label I needed to change to R.id.text1 which is the id of the TextView. Once I changed that it worked. 3 days I have been trying to get this thing working! Thanks! Now I just need to work out how to add the image.

Comment: @Jeremy oops...For some reason I read label. Good to hear you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Change the xml code to :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+navigate/RLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="50px"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
        android:layout_marginRight="20px"
        android:layout_marginTop="5px"
         >
</ImageView>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30px" >
</TextView></RelativeLayout>
```